# select highest value in mysql

Tags: mysql

So I have a database that has some values like this:

```
Level , Indicator

4       1
3       2
4       3
3       4
4       5
3       6
```

What I want to do is to select the highest level value in every indicator.

Is there any sql query that I can use that will generate a result like this?

```
Level , Indicator

4       1
4       3 
4       5
```

If not, can you help me out using php and mysqli? Thank you so much.

Comment: "what I want to do is to select the highest level value in every indicator." So why does your expected result only contain Level 4 ?

Comment: Have you tried any code? Can you share with us?

Comment: Your desired output isn't what you described in the question. Either correct the explanation, or correct the output.

Comment: The output looks like "all the rows with the highest level in the table".

Comment: Provided duplicate questions for both the text and the expected output of the question. Use whichever is convenient.

Answer (score 2):

To get `Indicators` having just highest `level` value -

```
select distinct Indicator, level
  from your_table
 where level = (select max(level) from your_table)
```

Also, you can use group by to get highest `level` for each `Indicator` value -

```
select Indicator, max(Level) from your_table group by Indicator
```

Comment: also you could employ window functions for operating on a set of rows and return a single value for each row from the underlying query